# Options on evaluating Recommender System

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, recommendation-engine

I've created a recommender system that works this way:

-each user selects some filters and based on those filters there's a score generated

-each user is clustered using k-means based on those scores

-whenever a user receives a recommandation i'm using pearson's correlation to see which user has the best correlation to other users from the same cluster

My problem is that i'm not really sure what would be the best way to evaluate this system? I've seen that one way to do it is by hiding some values of the dataset but that's not the case for me because i'm not predicting scores.

Are there any metrics or something that i could use?

Comment: Why that extra k-means step. Just find the most related user without k-means, it does not gain you anything.